# Count string values inside a string/list (FOR Loop)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have done extensive searching for an solution to my question however i have come up short, primarily because there is no example for loop using the conditions that i require.

**Question**

Use a for loop to count how many times the letter 'a' appears in the string 'fanta'.
Check your answer using Python’s string method called count().

Note: I am aware the question asks for how many times a appears in a string but i decided to use list.

**My attempt at the answer**

```
drink = ["f","a","n","t","a"]
letter = "a"

for letter in drink:
    print (letter)
```

Obviously there are two A's in fanta however i used the built-in count function to verify

```
count = drink.count('a')
print(count)
```

Indeed there are two A's in fanta :D

By the following train of thought; the for loop will look for letter "a" within the list drink, printing out

```
a
a
```

or something of the like, however i just get;

```
f
a
n
t
a
```

I am guessing because the for loop doesn't understand i only want it check for string letter inside the list.

**I would like to know**

How to get the desired result being in some way shape or form the for loop displaying a representation for how many a's in fanta.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess you haven't understood the for loop.

Comment: Nope, for loops are new to me

Comment: `for x in l:` overwrites any previous value of `x` while in the loop. It's not related to the outside `x` anymore, or in your case, `letter`.

Comment: @ stjepan, thanks mate i didn't know that. do any of you know of a good resource explaining for loops.

Comment: @bennyboy You can always check out the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> drink = ["f","a","n","t","a"]
>>> count = 0
>>> for c in drink:
        if c == 'a':
            count += 1


>>> count
2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
drink = ["f","a","n","t","a"]
letter = "a"

for each_char in drink:
    if each_char == letter:
        print char,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a one line list comprehension.

```
len([letter for letter in drink if letter == 'a'])
```

The reason your for loop isn't working the way you expect is that the `letter` variable in `for letter in drink` does not equal 'a'.  The for loop takes the argument for the item variable and the sequence variable.  `letter` is the item, and `drink` is the sequence.  So each item in `drink` is given the variable `letter` as you designated, one at a time, starting from the first index.

Comment: Lists have a `.count()` method as well, so there's no need to convert it to a string.

Comment: + you aren't allowed to use `.count` if you read the question

Comment: Didn't realize @Blender. Thanks

Comment: @jamylak Where does it say that? I see "Check your answer using Python’s string method called count()."

Comment: @bozdoz Yes that line exactly

Comment: Lol, no big deal but the question was to use a for loop only and check if i was correct with the count function

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to approach this is to do it the simplest most direct way possible.

```
>>> s = 'fanta'
>>> s.count('a')
2
```

Hoever, if you insist on a list, the correct way to count items in a list is with the `counter` module.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('fanta')
Counter({'a': 2, 'n': 1, 't': 1, 'f': 1})
>>> Counter('fanta')['a']
2
```

Note: A string is treated as a list of characters by Python automatically, so no need to create a special list ahead of time.